# R - polynomial regression issue - model limited to finite number of output values

Tags: r, polynomials, non-linear-regression

I'm trying to calculate point slopes from a series of x,y data. Because some of the x data repeats (...8, 12, 12, 16...) there will be a division by zero issue when using slope = (y2-y1/x2-x1).

My solution is to create a polynomial regression equation of the data, then plug a new set of x values (xx) into the equation that monotonically increase between the limits of x. This eliminates the problem of equal x data points. As a result, (x) and (xx) have the same limits, but (xx) is always longer in length.

The problem I am having is that the fitted values for xx are limited to the length of x. When I try to use the polynomial equation with (xx) that is 20 in length, the fitted yy results provide data for the first 10 points then gives NA for the next 10 points. What is wrong here?

```
    x <- c(1,2,2,5,8,12,12,16,17,20)
    y <- c(2,4,5,6,8,11,12,15,16,20)
    df <- data.frame(x,y)

    my_mod <- lm(y ~ poly(x,2,raw=T), data=df)     # This creates the polynomial equation 

    xx <- x[1]:x[length(x)] # Creates montonically increasing x using boundaries of original x
    yy <- fitted(my_mod)[order(xx)]

    plot(x,y)
    lines(xx,yy)
```

[tag-name](/questions/tagged/tag-name)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at

```
fitted(my_mod)
```

It outputs:

```
#       1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9        10 
#3.241032  3.846112  3.846112  5.831986  8.073808 11.461047 11.461047 15.303305 16.334967 19.600584
```

Meaning the name of the output matches the position of `x`, not the value of `x`, so `fitted(my_mod)[order(xx)]` doesn't quite make sense.

You want to use `predict` here:

```
yy <- predict(my_mod, newdata = data.frame(x = xx))
plot(xx, yy)

#        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9        10 
# 3.241032  3.846112  4.479631  5.141589  5.831986  6.550821  7.298095  8.073808  8.877959  9.710550 
#        11        12        13        14        15        16        17        18        19        20 
# 10.571579 11.461047 12.378953 13.325299 14.300083 15.303305 16.334967 17.395067 18.483606 19.600584
```

[image]

Comment: Figured this out - the problem is yy <- fitted(my_mod)[order(xx)]
This doesn't take in the new xx data correctly. The solution is to use...
yy <- predict(my_mod, newdata = data.frame(x = xx))

Comment: Hi @GregKawchuk yes apologies for initially misunderstanding your question (and also just now seeing your previous comment) - yes, `predict` is the function to model external data. Instead of deleting this answer, I updated/edited it to more appropriately address the question for other/future readers. Thanks again for clarifying and happy coding!